# Select a default option dropdown list in PHP

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown, html.dropdownlistfor

**This is the code I have:**

```
<?php
$PricerrTheme_enable_dropdown_values    = get_option('PricerrTheme_enable_dropdown_values');
                            $PricerrTheme_enable_free_input_box     = get_option('PricerrTheme_enable_free_input_box');
                            $x = (isset($_POST['job_cost']) ? $_POST['job_cost'] : $_SESSION['job_cost']);
echo PricerrTheme_get_variale_cost_dropdown('do_input', $x);
?>
```

**Q:** The options are selected from db, which are pricing sets like $1,$2,$3,$4,$5  etc. How do I select by default the $5 option instead of it currently defaulting to the lowest $1 option?

Answer (score 0):

use `selected="selected"`. also `<option selected>` this is also similer to the `selected="selected"`

```
    <option selected="selected">
       $5
    </option>
```

Comment: I have added it after the end ?> command.
The problem is, that it isn't selecting anything in the dropdown list, it is just displaying the text "$5" below the dropbox itself.

Comment: `<?php 
$PricerrTheme_enable_dropdown_values  = get_option('PricerrTheme_enable_dropdown_values');
$x = (isset($_POST['job_cost']) ? $_POST['job_cost'] : $_SESSION['job_cost']);
echo PricerrTheme_get_variale_cost_dropdown('do_input', $x);
?>
<option selected="selected">
       $5
</option>`

Comment: where is `select` tag??its not select